# row_factory alternative for mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I used row_factory in sqllite so that my rows can be returned in a dictionary format with column names. I used:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('gutendex.db')
conn.row_factory = dict_factory

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d
```

I want to use similar thing in mysql db as well but I couldnt find an alternative for it

Comment: If you use MySQL Connector, the `dictionary=True` parameter to `connection.cursor()` tells it to return rows as dictionaries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question does not has any answer and I solved the problem using the comment by Barmar I am pasting that as accepted solution.

The `dictionary=True` parameter to `connection.cursor()` tells it to return rows as dictionaries